# Multiple figures in a single row

Tags: floats

I am adding multiple figures in a single row with following code

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{image here} \\
    \small (a) Figure 1
  \end{tabular} \qquad
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{image here} \\
    \small (b) Figure 2
  \end{tabular} \qquad
 
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{image here} \\
    \small (c) Figure 3
  \end{tabular} \qquad
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{image here} \\
    \small (a) Figure 4
  \end{tabular} \qquad
```

The code works fine to add two figures per line, can some one help to add 3, 4 figures in the same. Unfortunately, I cannot use sub figure, it has some clashes with the journal paper template

Comment: Don’t leave a blank line after the second `tabular` environment. (All-blank lines trigger paragraph breaks.) oh, and do omit `\qquad` after the fourth tabular.

Comment: Did you try the `floatrow` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses tabular's less familiar cousin, tabular*, and his little friend `\extracolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \tabcolsep=0pt
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{example-image-c} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{example-image} \\
    \small (a) Figure 1 &
    \small (b) Figure 2 &
    \small (c) Figure 3 &
    \small (a) Figure 4
  \end{tabular*}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

Frankly, it is easier simply to compute the `\tabcolsep` needed to add up to `\linewidth` (2 per column).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \tabcolsep=0.2\linewidth
  \divide\tabcolsep by 8
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{example-image-c} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.20\linewidth]{example-image} \\
    \small (a) Figure 1 &
    \small (b) Figure 2 &
    \small (c) Figure 3 &
    \small (d) Figure 4
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach, which employs the `c` column type for all four columns, does not actually guarantee that the width of each column won't exceed `0.2\linewidth`. Why? It's because the widths of the "captions" are not constrained to be less than `0.2\linewidth`. You may want to point this out explicitly.

Comment: Of course a real \caption has to go inside a p{} column anyway (or a \parbox).

Answer (score 2):

- My main suggestion is that you omit the blank line after the 2nd of 4 images. Remember that blank lines are interpreted (in many, but not all text-mode situations) as paragraph break initiators. Hence the suggestion to omit the blank line.
- A further suggestion: omit the `\centering` instruction, omit the final `\qquad` directive, and replace the other 3 instances of `\qquad` with `\hfill`.
- Finally, if you have quite a few figures of this kind, it's probably worth creating a bespoke macro -- called `\myfig` in the code below -- to help streamline the creation of the subfigures.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\newcommand\myfig[2]{%
   \begin{tabular}[b]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}} 
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1} \\ \small #2 \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \myfig{image1}{(a) Figure 1}\hfill
  \myfig{image2}{(b) Figure 2}\hfill
  \myfig{image3}{(c) Figure 3}\hfill
  \myfig{image4}{(d) Figure 4}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `tabular` (or similar table) environment, by use of `subloat` environment (as defined in `subcaption` package version 1.3) and keys `Gin` you will get the shortest and simplest possible code for your problem:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.24\linewidth}
%
\subfloat[Figure 1]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}\hfill
\subfloat[Figure 2]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}\hfill
\subfloat[Figure 3]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}\hfill
\subfloat[Figure 4]{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]